# How do you move the contents of a randomly named folder to a new location when you dont know what the folder name will be?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, os.system

I am using requests to download an image with python.  That part works ok.  When I download a file I provide a name: **sitea.zip** .  When that file is decompressed it contains a folder with a random name, something like ZX234564563SDSD, that has a qcow2 image in it named gw-vm.qcow2.

I need to move the gw-vm.qcow2 to a specific folder for each site that I download an image for.

I can't figure out how to cd into that randomly named folder to get at the gw-vm.qcow2 file.

Right now I am using `os.system('unzip sitea.zip')` to decompress.

I don't know how to cd into the resulting folder to then perform the following:  `os.system('mv gw-vm.qcow2 /opt/unetlab/addons/qemu/sc-branch-a-1.0/gw-vm.qcow2')`

Any direction is appreciated.

Comment: Python comes with batteries included: use the [`zipfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) module instead of `os.system` for more control.

Comment: `os.listdir()` gets you the list of contents inside your path, which should be good enough if there's only that one file in there.

Comment: That did it @Jeronimo. Thanks for the help.  Once I had the listing I could move stuff around from there.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be a function of `os.walk()` -- it performs a dirwalk on a directory. Check out the docs on it: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?#os.walk

Good luck, hope that helps!

*(edited formatting)*

Comment: \* -- and then use string formatting to get into that dir, or into the `os.system` command -- `os.chdir( f"{root}/{folder}" )` or something like `os.system( f"mv {root}/{folder}/gw-vm.qcow2 ...")`